# usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu-15.04

I am attempting to link with the ncurses library. This doesn't work, though. These are the error messages:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile:102: recipe for target 'ch_lab' failed

make[1]: *** [ch_lab] Error 1
```

My question is, which package should I install to get this working on Ubuntu?

Comment: Install the ncurses library, perhaps? No evidence of either research effort or _thought_ in this question.

Answer (score 5):

You should install `libncurses`

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```